# Basis of group algebra factored by commutator

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

While reading through the proof of a theorem, I came across the following result, which was stated without proof:

> Let $k$ be a field, let $G$ be a finite group and let $kG$ be the corresponding group algebra. Let $g_1,\cdots,g_m$ be conjugacy class representatives of $G$. Then it is possible to show that $\mathcal{B} := \bigl(g_i + [kG,kG]\bigr)_{1 \leq i \leq m}$ is a $k$-vector space basis of $kG/[kG,kG]$.

Showing that $\mathcal{B}$ is a spanning set is not so difficult and follows from the fact that every $g \in G$ can be written as $g = xg_ix^{-1}$ for some $i$ and some $x \in G$.

On the other hand, I do not know how to prove linear independence of $\mathcal{B}$. If some $k$-linear combination $\sum (\lambda_i g_i + [kG,kG])$ were zero, then $\sum \lambda_i g_i = bc - cb$ for some $b,c \in kG$.

I would like to show that $\lambda_i \in [kG,kG]$ for all $i$. Does anybody have a suggestion on how I could do this? Otherwise, would there be a way to show that $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis from dimension counting?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a $k$-vector space, $[kG,kG]$ is generated by $xy-yx$ for $x$, $y\in G$.
Now $xy$ and $yx$ are conjugate in $G$. On the other hand if $g$ and $h$
are conjugate then $h=ugu^{-1}$ and
$g-h=(gu^{-1})u-u(gu^{-1})\in[kG,kG]$.

Let $A$ be the vector space with generators labelled $[C]$ where $C$
ranges over the conjugacy classes of $G$ and define a $k$-linear
map $\phi :kG\to A$ by taking $g\in G$ to $[C]$ where $C$ is the conjugacy
class of $g$. Then $\phi$ is surjective with kernel precisely $[kG,kG]$.
It follows that your $g_i+[kG,kG]$ form a basis for $kG/[kG,kG]$
since they are inverse images of a basis for $A$ (formed by the $[C]$).

Comment: Thank you very much! This is an extremely nice idea!